# Catching exceptions from different tasks running on different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, task, cancellation-token

I have  method running on a different task, which automatically runs on a different thread. I put the method in a try - catch block, and I want to catch when the cancellation token catches the OperationCancelledException exception, which it does, but when it quits and returns to the main thread, it disappears, and the cancellation token doesn't show it. Is there a way to solve this problem? I cannot show you the code because of company restrictions.

Comment: Is this a C# question?  Tag it properly!

Comment: "I cannot show you the code ..." - good. Then go to File|NewProject and write a [mcve]. Aim for 50 lines or less.